# Why is my window not over-writing its self every time it moves?

Tags: c, printing, c99, ncurses

So I am trying to have a 'blocker' in a city defense game

```
void *defense( void *maxBuildingHeight ){
    // the height to put the defense; 2 above the highest building
    int *defense_row = ((int *)maxBuildingHeight);
    int MAXX, MAXY;
    getmaxyx(stdscr,MAXY,MAXX); // screen rows and cols
    WINDOW *inputwin = newwin(1,5,(MAXY - (*defense_row + 2)),MAXX/2); //create the window for the defense
    char blocker[] = "#####";
    wprintw(inputwin, blocker); //the defense
    wrefresh(inputwin);
    keypad(inputwin, true); // collect the user input
    int newX = MAXX/2-2; // the left most position of the defense
    BlockerYSpot = (MAXY - (*defense_row + 2));

    while ( 1 ){
        int input = wgetch(inputwin);
        if (input == KEY_LEFT && (newX - 1) >= 0){
            newX--;
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            mvwin(inputwin, BlockerYSpot, newX);
            wrefresh(inputwin);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }
        else if (input == KEY_RIGHT && (newX + 5) < MAXX){ // its +5 due to the length of the blocker
            newX++;
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            mvwin(inputwin, BlockerYSpot, newX);
            wrefresh(inputwin);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        } else if (input == 'q'){
            delwin(inputwin);
            endwin();
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        CurrentBlockerXSpot = newX;
    }//while
}
```

my current output without moving left or right
[image]

My output when I move the blocker left, you can see that it doesn't erase the previous blocker.
[image]

Comment: Why is your function signature taking a `void*` which you immediately recast to `int*`? Just redeclare it if you can.

Comment: It's also really odd to see pthreads used here. Normally you do this sort of logic with a simple event loop. Threading can add considerable complexity that makes debugging these sorts of things unnecessarily hard.

Comment: Because this is a threaded function

Comment: This is for a project I do not have control of the design. Threading is not the problem in this situation

Comment: Before you commit too heavily to this flow, it's worth seeing if you can rework this into a simple non-blocking event loop. Using threading here creates a lot of control complexity. If you are using threading then one thread, and one thread only should be responsible for the display. The other should be manipulating a copy of the game state, and this gets switched out if/when the game is ready to render, but synchronizing that is non-trivial.

Comment: Try testing your display code independent of threading and/or game control concerns. It's hard to say what's wrong here. Once you get the drawing routines worked out, encapsulate those in well-defined functions you can call here.

Comment: The threading is not the problem I can guarantee you that. There is something wrong with my ncurses functions that I can't figure out

Comment: @Jak Please try to write a self-contained test program that demonstrates the display problem, without involving anything else - no game logic, no threads, no user input, just you run it and it draws the wrong thing.  You may discover the problem in the process, but even if you don't, it will be much easier for us to help you if we aren't getting distracted by "I wouldn't have done it this way" issues, and also if we can run the program for ourselves and tinker with it.

Comment: @Jak (Also, for future reference, people like tadman and I have seen hundreds of problems, here and elsewhere, that turned out to be caused by a bug in a part of the program that we didn't think could possibly be relevant.  So we tend to dig in our heels when someone says "X is not the problem, I guarantee it.")

Answer (score 0):

You're explicitly refreshing the `inputwin`, but not the window underneath.  Without seeing the rest of your code I'm assuming that it's the `stdscr`.  `refresh()` (or `wrefresh()`) the window underneath the "defense" to repaint the areas where the `inputwin` was.